# Dynamically adding normalizer to Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, serialization, dependency-injection

I am looking for a way to use a custom normalizer based on some conditions. Conditions being dependent on some parameter in the URL.

The normalizer I created gets autowired automatically, but I want to use it ONLY if a parameter is passed in the URL.

Is there a way to do this? Dynamically add the normalizer to the container in a request listener?

Currently if I set autoconfigure to `true`, it uses my normalizer, and set to `false`, it does not get used. But I need to make this configuration outside of the `services.yml` file.

```yaml
#services.yaml
  App\Framework\Serializer\CustomNormalizer:
    autoconfigure: false
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not how autowiring works. You'll need to put your logic somewhere else. Container compilation happens before any request is made, so it cannot be made dependant on parameters values.

But you can use the `supportsNomralization()` method and the `$context` to decide to use your normalizer or not.

```
public function supportsNormalization($data, string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        

        if (!$data instanceof Foo) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!\array_key_exists('foo_bar', $context) || $context['foo_bar'] !== '1') {
            return false;
        } 

        return true;
    }
```

And then when serializing your `Foo`, pass the appropriate parameter in the context if the parameter comes in the request:

```
$fooBar = $request->query->get('foo_bar');


$normalized = $this->serializer->normalize($someFoo, ['foo_bar' => $fooBar]);
```

This is a simple, untested example, but you should get the general idea to implement your own.

Again, implementing this on the DI layer is a no-go. The DI container is compiled ahead of time, so there is no information about the request there (nor should be).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking it needed to be something like this. However, I'm not sure at what point I can pass the query parameter to the normalize method in the $context, at this array seems to already be configured by the framework at some point.

Comment: You'll need to see where that's happening and try to work with that. But you cannot get around this with the DI layer.